# Cookie value is loosing after redirecting from payment gateway page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am loosing cookie value after it redirecting from payment gateway.

My code is as below;

```
internal static void CreateCookie(string CookieName, string CookieValue, double ExpiryDays)
    {
        HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie(CookieName, CookieValue);
        // myCookie.Value = CookieValue;
        myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(ExpiryDays);
        myCookie.Path = "/";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is you path value required?If it not required,delete this line.The cookie will be valid for all pages.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.path(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It is creating the same problem without path value